# Цикл (loop). Не могу понять почему цикл выдает результат меньше условия

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вот, к примеру, цикл:

```
     var ourArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
        ourArray.push(i);
     }
```

Результат: переменной ourArray присвоено массив 0,2,4,6,8. 
Вопрос: почему 10 не добавилось, ведь по логике цикл заканчивается после i=10?
Т.е. значения от 0 до 8 меньше 10 и, следовательно, к ним прибавляется 2. На i=10 цикл завершается, но числа 10 нет в массиве ourArray.
Прошу помочь

Comment: А это что у вас `i < 10`? Хотите 10, делайте `i <= 10` или `i < 11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что у вас `i < 10`, чтоб попала 10 надо написать `i <= 10`. Когда цикл доходит до 10, он делает проверку `10 < 10`, тк это `false`, цикл завершается и действие внутри цикла не выполняется.

Comment: Понятно, полдня голову ломал)) думал что на последнем цикле (после 8) добавляется последняя двойка и цикл завершается

Comment: @d.aky Если вопрос решён, отметьте один из ответов как решение. Для этого нажмите на серую галочку слева от ответа, чтобы она стала зелёной.

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть `<=`

```js
   var ourArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2) {
        ourArray.push(i);
     }
     console.log(ourArray)
```